# JUnit + Cucumber in IntelliJ - See Steps

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have a Cucumber project that is configured to run with Junit by configuring my Junit test with

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        extraGlue = "me.jkstrauss.stepdefs.common",
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber/cucumber.html"}
)
```

I am trying to run the test in IntelliJ, and everything works. The problem is that when I view the results, I can only see the individual scenarios, but not the steps.

[image: IntelliJ w/ JUnit]

Of course, I can run the features directly as a Cucumber Java test in IntelliJ, and I get the expected output.

[image: IntelliJ w/ Cucumber Java]

The problem is that I want to use some JUnit features, such as ClassRule, and those will not be run as part of the dedicated Cucumber Java test. Is there any way that I can get the itemized steps, and at the same time retain all the JUnit functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research on this topic I figured out that most of the JUnit plugin functionality can be replicated in Cucumber with a Cucumber plugin, so I am basically going to run all tests with the Cucumber plugin. I will still use Junit to run my tests from the command line, where the output goes to the screen either way, but when running Cucumber tests in IntelliJ I can just use the Cucumber plugin to accomplish whatever I wanted to do with Junit plugins.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"me.jkstrauss.HealthRunner$Resources"}
)
class HealthRunner {

    public static class Resources implements EventListener {

        @Override
        public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
            publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestRunFinished.class, it -> {
                // remove unsued resources
        });
    }
}
```

To activate the plugin in Cucumber Run configuration just add `--plugin me.jkstrauss.HealthRunner$Resources` to the "Program arguments".

Cucumber has many other events besides TestRunFinished. Look up API docs of https://javadoc.io/static/io.cucumber/cucumber-plugin/6.10.4/io/cucumber/plugin/event/EventPublisher.html for other options.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, when IDEA runs the tests directly Cucumber can communicate the results of individual steps. JUnits model however doesn't work well with sub-test steps and so they are omitted.

Currently the next version of Cucumber is scheduled to have beforeall and after all hooks.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will upvote your answer, as being correct. However, it does not help me though.